# Finding right variable from minified javascript code

Tags: javascript

All the variables after minifications are defined just with one or two letters. Is there any tool or technique which can help finding the right variable I am looking for in the javascript code?

For example, I found google doodle soccer game: https://www.google.com/logos/2012/football-2012-hp.html and now I try to find the variable there the score or final score is saved. So I can make the highscore table for the game.

Any tip is welcome.

Comment: Use this http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: Is there no developer documentation or something like that?

Comment: No source code, no documentation, no source map.

Answer (score 5):

There is a nice tool called [jsnice](http://jsnice.org)

> What is JSNice?
>
> JSNice is a new kind of statistical de-obfuscation and de-minification
> engine for JavaScript. Given a JavaScript program, JSNice
> automatically suggests new likely identifier names and types.

`jsnice` is different to other 'javascript beautifiers' in the fact it does not only formats the minified code, but is also predicts meaningful variable names.

Comment: I have to say in my case the jsnice is better than jsbeautifier. But my main goal is to watch variables to find the right variable. Beautification or de-minification of code help to do it manually if there is no tool what can help me digging the right variable from code.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you want to avoid working with the minified source. Try to find the original uncompressed source with the full variables names.

I have never been able to successfully make changes to a minified Javascript file. My Javascript skills are pretty good but minifiers make it very difficult to work out what the code is actually doing.

Source Maps are newer thing that help solve this problem: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/. But unfortunately in your case this will probably not work as Google has not provided a source map.

If you are forced to make changes to the minified source, try using some like http://jsbeautifier.org/ as @Mustafa_sabir suggested. Then try to figure out what each of the variables are. You could then either remember what they do or try renaming to something more meaningful.

Good Luck!

Comment: Its seems hacking Javascript games is not as popular as hacking PC games. I think minified code is not harder than hex code. So, only option is to do it in hard mode: beautify the code and use for example console.log to try out which variable has the same value as in-game score has?

Comment: Yeah... if your going to be modifying the minified source `console.log` is going to be your friend. Once you figure out what a variable does (even if it's not the one you need) try renaming it to a better name everywhere it appears. That way, as you work through your code, things will become more readable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to recover Minified Javascript variable names unless the Javascript code or library have a map file to decode the original code in the Inpsector view of the browser.

In your example, It is not possible.

Comment: Exactly. (Unless a *map-name* provided) Reverse engineering a minified code implies also one figuring out the inner-connections, relations and the underneath logic therefore re-naming the minified variable names into something meaningful. A pain.

Comment: Well, there are some tools which use a database of name and type regularities from large amounts of available open source code on GitHub such as [JSNice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24199255/1183010)